# Sorting in kendo grid not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to apply sorting in kendo grid but its not working. i want to sort by
 Date column then start_time column( Date + start_time).
I tried  sort:

```
[
              // sort by "JobDate" in ascending order and then by "Start_Time" in ascending order
              { field: "JobDate", dir: "asc" },
              { field: "StartTime", dir: "asc" }
                        ],
```

its working only for a page not for all data of grid.Please Let me know what can be issue. I also tried sever sorting but its also not working

Answer (score 0):

The "mode" attribute in sortable property should do the trick:

```
sortable: {
    mode: "multiple",
    allowUnsort: true
},
```